# Create Folders and Move Respective file into them

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

I have around 100 pdf files in a folder with name structure like:

- Credit Report - Google Inc
- Credit Report - BP Plc
- Credit Report - Apple Inc
- Credit Report - Saipem spa

So on and so forth.

Is there a command through which I new create new folders with names like :

- Google Inc
- BP Plc

and move the respective pdfs

- Credit Report - Google Inc
- Credit Report - BP Plc

into them.

Thanks

(PS: I am a first time user and struggling with text formatting on the forum, so please excuse any strange format)

Comment: Create VBS or PS script - do it in batch file form will be too complex.

Comment: Hi Akina - I am a normal windows user. How can i work with windows power shell?

Comment: So you want to create 100 folders each with 1 pdf in them that corresponds to filename?

Comment: Yes Smock, that's precisely what I want.

Answer (score 0):

### MoveToFolders.VBS

```vbs
FolderSpec="c:\tmp"
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set SourceFolder = FSO.GetFolder(FolderSpec)
For Each OneFile In SourceFolder.Files
    If LCase(Right(OneFile.Name, 4)) = ".pdf" and Instr(OneFile.Name, "-") > 0 Then
        FSO.CreateFolder FolderSpec & "\" & Trim(Split(Split(OneFile.Name, "-")(1), ".")(0))
        OneFile.Move FolderSpec & "\" & Trim(Split(Split(OneFile.Name, "-")(1), ".")(0)) & "\" & OneFile.Name
    end if
Next
```

Edit `"c:\tmp"`, set your source folder.

Only files with ".PDF" extension with a dash in the name are moved. If there is more than 1 dash then only the part between 1st and 2nd dashes is used.

Script will fail if any error occures (folder exists, file exists and so on). If you want to ignore errors add `On Error Resume Next` line before the first line.

Comment: Thanks Akina. So, I have to change the source folder (which would be same as parent folder) from temp before running this script. And am I going to run this script in simple command prompt?

Comment: @Kanu From command prompt or from Explorer - as you need. But remember - it is executed asynchronously, so you may wait a little until it finished its work.

Comment: What will happen in case there is a duplicate name after "-". Will the processing stop with error or override happens?

Comment: @Kanu Without error resume it will fail (stop with error). With error resume it will continue (you will obtain 2 files in a folder). Create test folder, put a lot of files in it, and test - you will see everything by yourself.

Comment: @Kanu I forget one more. If a name contains point(s) after a dash (except the point before the extension) then the tail after 1st point will be trimmed. But it can be easily fixed (if need, of course)

Comment: Sorry for stupid question, but where should i run this command please? It didnt work on CMD.

Comment: @Kanu I have tested it while starting in command line window (CMD) and by clicking in Explorer window. Both variants executes normally (I have used 4 names listed in your question after adding .PDF extension, and a lot of additional files which does not match pattern).

Comment: Each line of command to be run individually?

Comment: @Kanu I cannot understand what you have asked about.